# How to find columns name from the table with php

Tags: php, sql

Does any one know how can I find the column name for a selected table in php?

Exmaple:
If i have a table call customer as below:

```
cust_id    cust_name   cust_age
1          Alan        35      
2          Alex        52
3          Amy         15
```

How can I get the column name only in php when I select customer table (which it will return me value are cust_id, cust_name and cust_age)?

Comment: In PHP mysql_fetch_field,mysql_field_name would be helpful for you. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php

Comment: I presume you mean in MySQL? Be sure to be specific about your database in addition to the programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database is MySQL then, you can use mysql_field_name() and mysql_fetch_field() function in php.

```
$res = mysql_query('select * from customer', $link);

echo mysql_field_name($res, 0); // print cust_id
echo mysql_field_name($res, 1); // print cust_name 
echo mysql_field_name($res, 2); // print cust_age
```

You can check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php

If you want other information for fields then check this out
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php

Comment: I tried .. but error message display : Warning: mysql_field_name(): supplied resource is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: @Jin Yong: try this --> $res = mysql_query('select * from customer');

Comment: I tried both mysql_query('select * from customer') and mysql_query('select * from customer',$link). The same error display .. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL : `SHOW COLUMNS FROM customer;` OR `DESCRIBE customer;`

Answer (score 0):

[SHOW COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html) or use the [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) - the latter being more portable